# Using Gwt 2.7 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Is there a gwt 2.7 version of the eclipse plugin?

If i install the eclipse plugin from the official repository: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4

It will list "Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0" as the only version of GWT available. Is there no eclipse plugin for 2.7.0 ?

Comment: To answer you question: no there's no Eclipse plugin for 2.7.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plugin contains GWT 2.6.0.

To use GWT 2.7.0, download SDK from here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html

unzip it and add it as sdk to eclipse:

properties -> Google -> Web Toolkit -> configure sdk

use the add button to add the GWT 2.7.0 sdk to your workspace.

Comment: I installed the plugin, removed gwt 2.6 and added my local installation of gwt2.7 to the plugin. Now I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/dev/CompilerContext;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ResourceLoader;Z)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ModuleDef;
 if I try to run super dev mode

Comment: Are you using GWT Designer?

Comment: Nope, and I got it to work. The root cause was that my Main client project, depended on an other shared gwt project. And that Shared gwt project was still using gwt 2.6 which caused all kids of confusion for gwt.

Comment: By "add it as sdk to eclipse", he means add the sdk to a PROJECT within Eclipse.  Right click on the project and select properties...