# Projects using GWT 1.5 or lower may only specify one entry point module to compile

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse.
In https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-htmljs this tutorial I should Right click on html5 Project and select Google -> GWT Compile. When I click it I see popup window and disabled button Compile. I also see this error: "Projects using GWT 1.5 or lower may only specify one entry point module to compile.". Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to GWT 2.7, which has been out for a year and a half?

Comment: so I upgraded GWT to 2.7 based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626790/using-gwt-2-7-in-eclipse
and it works